# Binding knockout to external html

Tags: knockout.js

I have a button in my app that when clicked pops up a dialog window that will query data.  This windows uses jquery to call a $.get and load in a html form and add it to the DOM.  Once done it will use jQuery UI to show a modal dialog window.  I have a button on this form that submits the form data to the server.  Once I get the data back I want to bind this data to a table.  I am having trouble binding the button a view model and I have no clue how to bind the  results after I retrieve them.  Can anyone get me started with how to do this?

Comment: you need to be more specific @user1504973. Show us your code would help also.

Comment: Also, the question title is not accurate. You are not binding to external html, you are loading content via ajax and binding (which is actually very standard).

Answer (score 2):

When you get html from an ajax request, and you inject that into your page, you need to call applyBindings on the new element.

An example:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, $('#idOfNewElement')[0]);
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true. The HTML could already exist, and the binding data could be updated with the data from the ajax request.

Comment: but he said "when you get html"

Comment: @Tyrsius As I understand the question, he is getting unbinded html from an ajax request.

Comment: @aaberg Yea, but he seems kind of confused on what he is doing. I expect he is really only trying to get data, and just doesn't know the best way. He says in the first sentence "query data".